# How can I order map items in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to add low to high rates and high to low filter buttons and then show them with the order. but I couldn't figure out. how can I filter them?

`rate.retail_rate` is the data that I want to filter.

```js
type Props = {
  shipmentOptions: ShipmentRate[];
  isSelected?: boolean;
  setIsSelected?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
};

const USPSItems = ({ shipmentOptions, setIsSelected }: Props) => {
  const setSelectedRate = useShipmentRateStore(
    (state) => state.setSelectedRate
  );

  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const handlePress = (rate: ShipmentRate, index: number) => {
    setSelectedItem(index);
    setSelectedRate(rate);
    setIsSelected(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ShipmentRatesContainer>
        {shipmentOptions &&
          shipmentOptions.map((rate: ShipmentRate, index) => (
            <ClickableItem key={index} onClick={() => handlePress(rate, index)}>
              <PackagesActiveItem
                key={index}
                index={index}
                isSelected={index === selectedItem}
              >
                <PackagesItemIcon>
                  <SVGCustomIcon name="USPSLogo" />
                </PackagesItemIcon>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                  <PackagesItemLocation>{rate.carrier}</PackagesItemLocation>
                  <PackagesItemService>{rate.service}</PackagesItemService>
                </div>
                <PackagesItemRight>
                  <PackagesItemRightText>
                    ${rate.retail_rate}
                  </PackagesItemRightText>
                </PackagesItemRight>
                <USPSItemBottomText>
                  Estimated to arrive{" "}
                  {rate.est_delivery_days
                    ? "in " + rate.est_delivery_days + " business days"
                    : "within the next day"}
                </USPSItemBottomText>
              </PackagesActiveItem>
            </ClickableItem>
          ))}
      </ShipmentRatesContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: use [.sort((a,b) => ...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#syntax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_with_map
This code is from the link above:

```
    // the array to be sorted
    const data = ['delta', 'alpha', 'charlie', 'bravo'];
    
    // temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
    const mapped = data.map((v, i) => {
      return { i, value: someSlowOperation(v) };
    })
    
    // sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
    mapped.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.value > b.value) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.value < b.value) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    
    const result = mapped.map((v) => data[v.i]);
```